# MySQL subquery using INSTR to exclude records

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am trying to create a MySQL subquery that will retrieve the records from table1, only if the records from table2 do not exist anywhere within the table1 record.  Here is my schema:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  CompanyName VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  ExcludeName VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
( 'COMPANY AAA 111' ),
( 'COMPANY BBB 222' ),
( 'COMPANY CCC 333' ),
( 'COMPANY DDD 444' ),
( 'COMPANY EEE 555' );

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES
( 'BBB' ),
( 'DDD' );
```

And here is my SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.CompanyName 
   FROM table1 t1
   JOIN table2 t2
       ON INSTR(t1.CompanyName, t2.ExcludeName ) = 0;
```

As shown in this [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68766/2/0), I am not getting the correct result.  I want the query to return only `COMPANY AAA 111`, `COMPANY CCC 333` and `COMPANY EEE 555`, but instead the query is returning all of the records.  Why aren't the `BBB` and `DDD` records being excluded?

Comment: @Barmar - I am struggling with this.  Would you mind taking a look at my fiddle and see what I am doing wrong?  Many thanks.

Comment: Your fiddle is the same as the code in the question. Have you tried implementing the solutions in the question I linked to? Just change the `=` condition to use `INSTR`, but the rest of the structure should be the same.